# SpeechRecognizer is not working if Enhanced Google services is selected

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice, google-voice, google-voice-search

The voice input in my application does not work if I select "Enhanced Google services" in Voice input Settings (please see screenshot):

[image]

I use speech recognition without a dialog:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyRecognitionListener listener = new MyRecognitionListener();
    sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
    sr.setRecognitionListener(listener);

    findViewById(R.id.bt1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);    
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.query");           
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en_US");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en_US");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en_US");
            sr.startListening(intent);
       }
   });     
}
```

Could you please help, what can be the problem?

Comment: Which version of Android and Google are you using?

Comment: Nexus 10 with Android v5.1.1

Comment: Please can you post the unfiltered logcat when you attempt to run your code. When the Google application detects that another application requires the mic (it can do this because it's a system application), it should release the mic resources and the logcat should show this output.

Comment: E/SpeechRecognizer﹕ bind to recognition service failed

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: Still not resolved